# bower and requirejs configure paths

Tags: requirejs, bower

what is best practice for this situation i use requirejs, I download

```
bower install pdfmake
```

get

```
└── bower_components
    └── pdfmake
        ├── bower.json
        ├── build
        │   ├── pdfmake.js
        │   ├── pdfmake.min.js
        │   ├── pdfmake.min.js.map
        │   └── vfs_fonts.js
        ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
        └── LICENSE
```

i see inside some configuration files - bowej.json, pdfmake.min.js.map

how i should correct map this lib in requirejs config.

```
requirejs.config({
  "paths": {
   'pdfmake': '/bower_components/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js',
  },
"shim": {
  'pdfmake': {
            deps: ["/bower_components/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"]
        },
}

})
```

this is correct configuration way?

i see in https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake  just

```
npm install pdfmake
require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js'); and require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
```

without configure require ? can i use some magic to auto map bower installed libs ? like in https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake example

Answer (score 0):

the best practice according to bower.io is to use yarn+webpack: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/